# Javascript soap client, browser ignores cookies

Tags: javascript, soap, soap-client

I am trying to work with soap client at the browser. For that, I am using [soap js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).

I tried to use soap client in the browser. Everything works fine except for session authorization. I have splitted api into 8 services. So I need to create 8 different Soap Client instances and share session between them, but I can't make it work. The weird thing is that response is returning "Set-cookie" header but browser don't write it in cookies and next Soap Client do request like from another session and gets "Set-cookie" again which is ignored again. Can somebody explain to me why it's happening? Why browser ignores "Set-cookie" in response? And if somebody knows how to deal with my problem it would be very nice to give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

[Request and response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvncM.png)

[Cookies at localhost:3001 after successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6uyw.png)

Comment: Can edit your question to include the `set-cookie` header? It would be helpful to see if there are any special directives like `domain`, `expires`, `secure`, etc. Feel free to redact/change the cookie value if it's sensitive.

Comment: @David784 I added screenshots with request and response headers and Browser storage after a successful request. Maybe it will help to understand the current case. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be a secure directive or something, but looks okay. the `httponly` directive means you won't be able to see the cookie from JavaScript, but you should still see it in the dev tools. That second screen shot doesn't look right to me though...that only appears to be storage size, not a cookie listing. In chrome the cookies would be listed in the dev tools, Application tab, storage section, expand the cookies subsection and choose the correct domain.